# Estimating system of simultaneous equation with Genetic Algorithms

Tags: genetic-algorithm

I have to estimate a simultaneous equation system (regressions) with about 11 equations and 21 variables.

I estimated by 2SLS method in econometric and now I want to estimate it with genetic algorithm. Can any one help me on how to start? Is there any paper related to this(estimation of simultaneous equation with GA)? Do you know what should my fitness function be?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Grammatical Evolution.  You provide a list of the variables, available functions and a fitness evaluation function.  The program will use genetic algorithms to produce genomes that map to different programs to evaluate.  Using the fitness function to minimize error, it will evolve a program to solve the problem.

One possible implementation to use is [GEVA](http://ncra.ucd.ie/Site/GEVA.html) which is implemented in JAVA.

If you don't know how many equations are involved in a complex dataset, you will probably want to look into using meta-grammars to define the available functions and variables.  I'd need to know more about the specific problem to give any better advise.

Comment: Thank you Nick for your answer.In fact I have to estimate Simultaneous Structural Equation Model with algorithm genetic and compare the result with 2SLS estimation about this model. the model is macroeconomic model include 10 equation and about 21 variables for about 46 year, I mean  data of each variable exist for 46 years. I read many papers about SEM but  unfortunately they are about specification of the simultaneous model with GA  not estimation with GA.